# Check if Sympy Expression is Nan?

Tags: python, nan, sympy

How do I check if a sympy expression evaluates to nan?

I simply need to do something like this:

```
if is_nan( expression ):
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: `if expression == sympy.NaN`? I'm not sure where exactly `NaN` lives in the sympy library, but I know it is a pre-defined constant.

Comment: I guess that works

Comment: To defend my intelligence -> numpy won't recognize equality this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SymPy, `==` always checks structural equality (that is, if two expressions are exactly equal). This works even for nan, so there is no need for a separate `isnan` function (strictly speaking, SymPy's nan isn't an IEEE 754 nan).

Answer (score 8):

In sympy, you can check for equality with the sympy nan object:

```
>>> alpha = sympy.nan
>>> alpha == sympy.nan
True
```

In numpy, you cannot check for equality with the numpy nan object:

```
>>> alpha = numpy.nan
>>> alpha == numpy.nan
False
>>> numpy.isnan(alpha)
True
```

Hence there exists a numpy.isnan() method, and there does not exist a sympy.isnan() method.

Credit to  Morgan Thrapp

Answer (score 0):

You can use some logic like:

```
value * 0 == 0
```

Comment: This does not fully work since this expression will also be false if value variable is infinity.